# Can't get the value from a JSON object using Python

Tags: python, json

```
import requests
import json

s = requests.Session()
s.params["key"] = "MY_KEY"
s.params["cx"] = "MY_CX"
s.params["num"] = 1

result = s.get('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1', params={"q": "Search query"})
```

Everything is working fine and I do get a result back but it's JSON. What I want is one thing. Since my result only gives 1 search result, I want the link of that search result. From I've understood that link value is under the keys "item" and then "link". I've tried lots of things but I keep getting either one of these errors below.

```
TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

NameError: name 'json' is not defined

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'Response'
```

What am i doing wrong and what's the solution?

Comment: Can you add the code that produce the error?

Comment: You're getting back a `Response` object.  The actual content is in the `text` attribute (`result.text`), and it's a JSON string, so you would need to convert it into Python objects first, using either the `json` module or just using the `result.json()` method.

Comment: This is all covered with examples [in the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).